# Too many re-renders error while trying to hide/show element on state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

`const [show, setShow] = useState(false)`

```
{(name == "" || lastName == "" || birthday == "" || number == "")&&setShow(!show)}
 <div className={`${handles.saveButtonOne}`} style={{ display: show === false ? 'none' : 'block' }} onClick={submitData}>SAVE ACCOUNT</div>
```

Getting this error:
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

I do not know where did I create an infinite loop. At least for me, it looks quite simple, if state is "" don't show

pd: This error only happens when I leave one input empty

Comment: setShow(!show) means it sets true -> false -> true -> false every render. change it to setShow(false). But even then it won't work.  write setShow only if it triggers change in show value

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
(name == "" || lastName == "" || birthday == "" || number == "") && setShow(!show)
```

to:

```
[name, lastName, birthday, number].some(val => val === "") && !show
```